# How to remember Filter values for second time request in Kendo Grid?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using `Kendo Grid` to display records in my MVC web application. What I want is, when I filter the grid with some value, and request for some another page from that page, and when I again request for that grid page, I want that my filter value will becomes as its was set in previous request.

Answer (score 3):

I do it the following way:
First you have to store the current filter somewhere - I use javaScript's localStorage. This is persistent as long as the browser cache is not cleared.
You could do this for example when leaving the page etc.

```
// get the grid as js object
var grid = $("#yourGridID").data("kendoGrid");

// Store the current filter (must be a string, so use JSON)
localStorage["myFilter"] = JSON.stringify(grid.dataSource.filter().filters)
```

To restore the filter, you can call

```
grid.dataSource.filter(JSON.parse(localStorage["myFilter"]))
```

This should be done after the grid has been initialized, for example in the *dataBound* event of your grid. Of course you should check if `localStorage["myFilter"]` exists.

If you want to save other things like column withs/order, sorting etc, too, you can also use `grid.getOptions(options)` and `grid.setOptions(options)` to save and restore the complete grid settings. These options can also be saved in the localStorage (use JSON here, too)